# Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss

Tags: firefox, websocket, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm developing webchat and got an error on Firefox.

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations

I tested on Chrome and Edge works fine, only Firefox could not connect. 
I'm working on proxy network.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by initial websocket in javascript.

```
new WebSocket("wss://directline.botframework.com");
```